# Resizing window using SDL and OpenGL

Tags: opengl, sdl, sdl-2, opengl-2.0

Before writing this question, I have read the question: [Handling window resizing using OpenGL and SDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138559/handling-window-resizing-using-opengl-and-sdl). However that question does not solve my problem, since I am using SDL2 and not SDL1.2. But I do use OpenGL2. My complete source code is available at: http://dpaste.com/17BVBP6

I am writing a program that displays a white square in the window. However I am having trouble while handling window resize events.Here is my resize function:

```
void resize(int width,int height)
{
    if(height<=0)    height=1;

    glViewport(0,0,(GLsizei)width,(GLsizei)height);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(60.0f,float(width)/float(height),1.0f,100.0f);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}
```

My Main event loop:

```
while( !quit )
        {
            while( SDL_PollEvent( &e ) != 0 )
            {
                switch (e.type) {
                case SDL_QUIT:
                    quit=true;
                    break;
                case SDL_WINDOWEVENT_SIZE_CHANGED:
                    resize(e.window.data1,e.window.data2);
                    break;
                case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                    switch (e.key.keysym.sym) {
                    case SDLK_ESCAPE:
                        quit=true;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                    }
                default:
                    break;
                }
            }

            render();

            update(gWindow);
        }
```

Here is my window when it is not resized:
[image: Rendering is done properly when not resized]

Here is my window when it is resized:
[image: Rendering is not properly done when resized]

What is the causing the problem here??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`SDL_WINDOWEVENT_SIZE_CHANGED` is not an event type, it is variation of `SDL_WINDOWEVENT`. Your event checking should be like

```
switch(e.type) {
    case SDL_WINDOWEVENT:
        if(e.window.event == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_SIZE_CHANGED) {
            resize(e.window.data1,e.window.data2);
        }
        break;
```

Also remove your perspective projection setting - it is inconsistend with your draw, and you don't have perspective setup before resize.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed the problem.